# Scroll to id href without #

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm developing a site and I'd like to make people scroll to an href id without showing it in the navigation bar of their browsers. If is it possible I'd like to do it with

Am I able to do it? Thanks

Example: index.html#id

How I want it: index.html

Comment: If you know which ID you want to scroll to then yes, you are able to

Comment: Why do you want to disable the hashes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Element.scrollIntoView` to achieve this. The javascript needed is

```
var scrollToElement = function(id){
    document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
}
```

If you pass in `{behaviour: 'smooth'}` to the function you get smooth scrolling which is really slick.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView for further documentation on this function

Answer (score -1):

## pure JS version

Using `window.scrollTo(x,y)` you can move the viewport:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("your element id");
window.scrollTo(0, elem.offsetTop);
```

## jQuery Version

If you are already using jQuery, you can use `.animate()` for a smooth scroll transition to the element.

Here is an example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

[See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: jquery is not in the tag list

Comment: @Huangism I have added a pure js version

Comment: Good work, although I am not the one who downvoted you